# Unable to install/update any packages through NuGet manager

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am unable to install/update any library through NuGet.I have tried restoring Nuget for solution, clearing NuGet cache, restarting VS and even restarting the system. 
I am getting below mentioned errors

Tried to install System.Data.OleDb

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Error downloading 'System.Data.OleDb.4.6.0' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.data.oledb/4.6.0/system.data.oledb.4.6.0.nupkg'.
End of Central Directory record could not be found.**

Tried to update System.IO.Packaging

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Error downloading 'System.IO.Packaging.4.6.0 : System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives [4.3.0, )' from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.io.packaging/4.6.0/system.io.packaging.4.6.0.nupkg'.
End of Central Directory record could not be found.**

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a while back and resolved it by deleting Nuget.config from %APPDATA%\NuGet as per Henrick Andersson's blog : https://medium.com/@hnrkndrssn/nuget-restore-error-end-of-central-directory-record-could-not-be-found-3908129dbac5.  Hope that helps.